# ユーザの回答一覧をスマホで並べ替えるとソート順が設定コンボボックスと食い違う

Tags: バグ, デザイン, モバイル

AndroidスマホでSOjaなどのユーザ情報を開き、下記の操作を行うと回答一覧などのソート順の表示に齟齬が発生します。

1. 任意のユーザ情報→アクティビティタブを開く
2. 回答一覧の右にある『並べ替える』コンボを現在選択中のものから別のものに変更する
   (例えば`票`→`新着`)
3. 任意の項目をタップして回答のリンク先に画面遷移する
4. 画面下のナビバーで『`戻る◁`』ボタンをタップする

上記の例において、手順2では一覧のソート順(`新着`)とコンボの表示(`新着`)が一致します。
しかし手順4で戻った後、一覧のソート順は変更後(`新着`)のままですが、コンボの表示(`票`)がソート変更前の値に戻ってしまいます。

[image: ソート順の表示がおかしい]

この状態でソート順を票数順に戻すには、コンボの`票`を一旦`新着`などに変更してから`票`に再変更しないといけないので、ひと手間増えます。

PCでは発生しないようです。
iPhoneやタブレットは試していませんので、スマホ向けのレスポンシブデザインで必ず発生するかどうかは分かりません。

なお本家SO他でも発現するため既知の不具合かもしれませんが、メタサイトで報告済みかどうかも調べておりません。
非常に緊急度の低い不具合と思いますが、ご報告いたします。

発生した環境:
Android 9
Chrome 86.0.4240.198